# Display category name from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables in my database. One name jokes and the other named category.

jokes

```
CREATE TABLE `jokes` (
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `joke` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`joke_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

category

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

and i was wondering what the query would be to find the category name of a joke so it can be displayed on the home page like title:"Celebrity Joke" joke:"Miley Cyrus is a joke" and so on..

Would anybody be able to help me out on this problem, im guessing it will be a query/string assigned to a variable named $category_name which will reference both tables, but again, im not too sure how to go about it.

Comment: I would image it would be something like: `SELECT jokes.*,category.* FROM jokes LEFT JOIN category ON jokes.category_id=category.category_id WHERE 1=1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this first joining two tables:

```
SELECT
* //You can filter more your columns here
FROM
jokes
LEFT JOIN category ON
jokes.category_id = category.category_id
```

Now after this statement you can add a WHERE CLAUSE and it could be something like this

```
WHERE category.category_name like '%Miley%'
```

Means you will retrieve records having a category that has name of Miley

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to do this with all jokes/categories it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes UNION SELECT * FROM category
```

However if you wanted to do a single joke you could just use the answer posted by Drixson. IF you wanted all the jokes from one category you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE category_id=CATEGORY_ID
```

Some PHP you could use to display jokes from each category:

```
//Cat ID, using 1 for example
$category = 1

//Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE category_ID=:cat";

//Establish PDO, prepare, apply parameter, execute, fetch data 
$search = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DB",USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$runQuery = $search->prepare($query);
$search->bindParam(':cat', $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$search->execute();
$results = $search->fetchAll();

//For every row display joke_id and the joke
foreach($results as $joke){
    echo $jokes["joke_id"] . " - " . $jokes["joke"];
}

//Kill   
$results = null;
```

Hope it helps. PDO is pretty easy to pick up so if you need anymore help just search for a PDO tutorial on Google.